# Nimbus theme gone in newest Intellij (13.0.2)

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

IntelliJ upgrade and bang! My favourite theme is gone.
How can I easily grab Nimbus theme for the newest IntelliJ ?

They even didn't mention such a breaking change in release notes :)

Same is true for newest versions of other JetBrains IDEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a special key

-Dshow.all.look.and.feels=true

in idea.exe.vmoptions file (/bin/idea.exe.vmoptions)

Comment: Impressive. Even google doesn't know about "show.all.look.and.feels" property. Are you the one that made that change in Intellij? :>

For the people using 64 bit operating systems: the file to be edited is `idea64.vmoptions` and `idea64.exe.vmoptions` on windows.

Comment: The trick with the property is not longer working as of Intellij 13.1.4. I suppose you're on JetBrains dev team. Guys… c'mon… why on earth remove so many cool themes?